# How to Install Testdisk in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation, testdisk

I am unable to install testdisk in Ubuntu 13.10 from Live Disk.
I am using USB drive to run ubuntu 13.10. I want to recover some data from Windows partition.

I am unable to install testdisk. It is a tar.bz2 file. I have extracted it in a directory.

Can someone help me with the steps to install the application.

Comment: It's all explained in my answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu (provided you have internet access on that machin, do you?)

Answer (score 8):

You can install [testdisk [image: Install testdisk]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk) with apt-get

First, you have to enable the universe repository

[image: repos]

Then update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Software_Tab for additional information on repositories.

Comment: Hi minerz, I tried the above command. I am getting the following  root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk

Comment: you have to enable the universe repository - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Software_Tab, then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install testdisk`