# Unable to load Windows 10 after selecting from GRUB menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

OK so i know this will be marked as duplicate because it looks very similar to many other issues people have had.

Hear me out:
I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, after a bit of troubleshooting it managed to boot into Ubuntu from the GRUB menu.

Now, when i select "Windows Boot Manager" from the GRUB menu, i get the Windows blue screen with an error saying "can't access device".

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000e  

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

The previous trouble shooting involved deleting a partition on my SSD that i assumed was the partition that i created for Ubuntu. I have a feeling deleting this partition may have caused the issue but i cannot see how.

I have tried pretty much every fix i can find on askubuntu and nothing has worked, i just seem to keep adding more useless options to my GRUB menu.

Has anyone else had this issue?

The error code that Windows throws me is: 0xc000000e

Comment: Before deleting anything else you might want to run `testdisk`: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix This might seem like a stupid question - but how do you run this? I'm new to linux so i don't understand how you run it when the download gives me lots of files in a zipped folder.

Comment: Lots of answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/398335/how-to-install-testdisk-in-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erased Ubuntu partition, now computer will not boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828825/erased-ubuntu-partition-now-computer-will-not-boot)

Comment: Are you booting into Ubuntu OK?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I rant testdisk and the partitions can't be recovered :/

Comment: @PaulBenson Yes Ubuntu boots fine, its what im using right now

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HxDe6qd.png If it helps, these are the current partitions on the drive. The 54 GB partition is what i have allocated for Ubuntu.

Comment: You are showing the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration with a brand new SSD. Did you install Windows yourself in wrong boot mode? How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. But you will have to temporarily install a BIOS Windows boot loader to MBR, boot Windows and make repairs. Maybe chkdsk, but probably turn off fast start up. Grub only boots working Windows.  And Windows will turn fast start up back on with updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: There's all kinds of reasons why this problem might occur, not least a physical problem with the SSD which I'm excluding for now. I need to see your grub file. Run `grep -i windows -A10 /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and print output